# How do I choose a denominator based on the values in another data frame?

Tags: r, if-statement, comparison-operators

My task is to calculate the ratio of academic credits per student/expected academic credits (with no courses failed) during the time period. Since I have got limited access to university databases, I have to create a reference table for each class, where I can see what the amount of credits the students should have attained given the current date.

My reference table will look something like this (I haven't yet gathered data from more than one class though):

```
   Cred   Sumb weeks startdate  ExpCred Start_date_points End_date_points
1   15.0    0   10  2018-09-02  0.0     2018-09-02        2018-12-01
2   15.0    0   10  2018-09-02  15.0    2018-12-02        2019-02-09
3   15.0    0   10  2018-09-02  30.0    2019-02-10        2019-04-20
4   15.0    0   10  2018-09-02  45.0    2019-04-21        2019-06-29
5   7.5     1   5   2018-09-02  60.0    2019-06-30        2019-10-26
6   7.5     1   5   2018-09-02  67.5    2019-10-27        2019-11-30
7   15.0    1   10  2018-09-02  75.0    2019-12-01        2020-02-08
8   7.5     1   5   2018-09-02  90.0    2020-02-09        2020-03-14
9   7.5     1   5   2018-09-02  97.5    2020-03-15        2020-04-18
10  15.0    1   10  2018-09-02  105.0   2020-04-19        2020-06-27
11  15.0    2   10  2018-09-02  120.0   2020-06-28        2020-11-28
12  15.0    2   10  2018-09-02  135.0   2020-11-29        2021-02-06
13  30.0    2   20  2018-09-02  150.0   2021-02-07        2021-06-26
14  0.0     2   0   2018-09-02  180.0   2021-06-27        2021-06-26
15  15.0    0   10  2019-09-03    0.0   2019-09-03        2019-12-02
16  15.0    0   10  2019-09-03   15.0   2019-12-03        2020-02-10
17  15.0    0   10  2019-09-03   30.0   2020-02-11        2020-04-20
18  15.0    0   10  2019-09-03   45.0   2020-04-21        2020-06-29
19  7.5     1   5   2019-09-03   60.0   2020-06-30        2020-10-26
20  7.5     1   5   2019-09-03   67.5   2020-10-27        2020-11-30
21  15.0    1   10  2019-09-03   75.0   2020-12-01        2021-02-08
22  7.5     1   5   2019-09-03   90.0   2021-02-09        2021-03-15
23  7.5     1   5   2019-09-03   97.5   2021-03-16        2021-04-19
24  15.0    1   10  2019-09-03   105.0  2021-04-20        2021-06-28
25  15.0    2   10  2019-09-03   120.0  2021-06-29        2021-11-29
26  15.0    2   10  2019-09-03   135.0  2021-11-30        2022-02-07
27  30.0    2   20  2019-09-03   150.0  2022-02-08        2022-06-27
28  0.0     2   0   2019-09-03   180.0  2022-06-28        2022-06-27
```

When I try to use my reference table in calculations, however, I run into problems. I write:

```
fulldata<-fulldata%>%mutate(PERC_CREDIT=CREDITS/ifelse(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM==ekon_program$sd & Sys.Date()>=ekon_program$finished_date,180,
ifelse(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM==ekon_program$sd & Sys.Date()>=ekon_program$start_date_points & Sys.Date()<=ekon_program$end_date_points,ekon_program$points_expected,100000 )))
```

And get the following error messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM == ekon_program$sd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM == ekon_program$sd & Sys.Date() >=  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM == ekon_program$sd :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM == ekon_program$sd & Sys.Date() >=  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
5: In UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM == ekon_program$sd & Sys.Date() >=  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

What I want to do is to choose a denominator based on the information in my reference table. First and formost I want to limit the observations the calculations are based on to the ones with the same starting point for the program as the one for the current observation in the main table.

If the current sys.date() exceeds the calculated end date for the program (starting at that specified date) in the reference table, I want the denominator to be set to 180.

If the sys.date is less than that, I want it to reflect the value of *points_expected* for whatever observation in the reference table (with the same starting point for the program as the current observation in the main table) where the current sys.date falls between the values of *start_date_points* and *end_date_points*.

How can I make this happen and what am I doing wrong?

Excerpt main table

```
structure(list(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM = c("2018-09-03", 
"2018-09-03", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-03"
), CREDITS = c(30, 0, 22.5, 9.5, 0, 54)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Excerpt reference table:

```
structure(list(sd = c("2018-09-03", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-03", 
"2018-09-03", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-03"), points_ekon = c(15, 
15, 15, 15, 7.5, 7.5), summer_break_ekon = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
), weeks_course = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5), points_expected = c(0, 
15, 30, 45, 60, 67.5), order = 1:6, start_date = structure(c(17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776), class = "Date"), start_date_points = structure(c(17776, 
17867, 17937, 18007, 18077, 18196), class = "Date"), end_date_points = structure(c(17866, 
17936, 18006, 18076, 18195, 18230), class = "Date"), finished_date = structure(c(18805, 
18805, 18805, 18805, 18805, 18805), class = "Date")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    start_date = structure(17776, class = "Date"), .rows = list(
        1:6)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Not actually about the problem, but spaces and indentation in your code will go a long way in making it readable and easier to edit and debug

Comment: I tried running your code where the main table is the variable fulldata and the reference table is the variable ekon_program and I couldn't replicate your error as it ran for me.

Comment: Indeed, using posted data and replacing `mutate` for base R's `transform`, no errors or warnings are raised: https://rextester.com/TZGJV98320

Comment: I run your code and get the exakt same error message? I can't post entire dataset due to regulations :(

Comment: Since neither mutate nor transform seems to work I'm trying to select one relevant value for "points_expected" per class and performing a join with those values where the start dates match:

fulldata<-ekon_program%>%filter(Sys.Date()>finished_date|(Sys.Date()>=start_date_points & Sys.Date()<=end_date_points))%>%select(sd,points_expected)%>%full_join(fulldata, by=c("sd"="UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM"))

Comment: So far this seems to work.